# Are there any perfect squares of the form $\underbrace{88\cdots8}_{n\text{ times}}1$ (in decimal, at least two $8$'s)?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, decimal-expansion, diophantine-approximation

I saw this problem recently and it is deceptively hard.  The usual $\pmod{4}$ trick won't work, and indeed there will be perfect squares whose last $n$ digits will be $\underbrace{88\cdots8}_{n\text{  times}}1$ , for any $n$.

I can show that if $\underbrace{88\cdots8}_{n\text{  times}}1$ is a perfect square, $2n$ digits total, then the decimal representation of $\sqrt{8/9}$ must start with $n$ digits followed by almost that many zeroes (like $n-1$ or so).  This seems preposterous, but I can't figure out how to rule it out.  I've thought of using continued fractions, since there is a limit on how well $\sqrt{8/9}$ can be approximated with rationals, but I can't seem to get a tight enough inequality.  Maybe someone with more expertise in Diophantine approximation can answer this?

Note: even if you can prove that there aren't infinitely many perfect squares of this form, even if you don't have a computable bound on how large they might be, I'd still be interested.

Comment: I doubt the Diophantine approximation angle will be that helpful unless the property of being a power of $10$ can be used in a particularly clever way -- the continued fraction convergents to $\sqrt{8/9}$ should be better approximants (by a constant factor) than the ones which arise from solutions to this problem.

Comment: @carl That's true, but the continued fraction coefficients for $\sqrt{8/9}$ are: $[0;1,\overline{16,2}]$, and I'm sure that if pressed, we could prove that none of the denominators is a power of 10.  Can we get a better badness-of-approximation bound for rationals that AREN'T a continued fraction convergent?

Comment: We may not get all the figits preceding the final $1$ to equal $8$. But we can get half of them to do so, in some cases a little more.

Comment: In case it helps, $\underbrace{88\cdots8}_{n\text{  times}}1 = \frac{8 \times 10^{n + 1} - 71}{9}$.

Answer (score 3):

The number $88\cdots81$ in general form is

$$
(10^n - 1){8 \over 9} - 7 \text{ where } n \text{ is the total number of digits.}
$$

If we need this to be a perfect square, we need to solve the Diophantine equation

$$
(10^n - 1){8 \over 9} - 7 = y^2, y \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

This implies

$$
y = \pm \bigg({1 \over 3} \sqrt{2^{n + 3} 5^{n} - 71}\bigg)
$$

The term under the radical needs to be a perfect square for $y$ to be an integer and also a multiple of $9$. $\text{i.e.,} \exists x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that,

$$
2^{n + 3} 5^{n} - 71 = (3x)^2
$$

**Case 1 ($n$ is even):**

Since $n$ is even, we may take $n = 2m$ and rewrite the equation as

$$
2^3(10)^{n} - 71 = (3x)^2 \\
\implies 2^3(10)^{2m} - 71 = (3x)^2 \\
\implies 8(10^m)^{2} - 71 = (3x)^2
$$

Taking $10^m = Y, 3x = X$,

$$
8Y^{2} - X^2 = 71
$$

This is a Pell equation.

**Case 2 ($n$ is odd):**

Since $n$ is odd, we may take $n = 2m+1$ and rewrite the equation as

$$
2^3(10)^{n} - 71 = (3x)^2 \\
\implies 2^3(10)^{2m+1} - 71 = (3x)^2 \\
\implies 80(10)^{2m} - 71 = (3x)^2 \\
\implies 80(10^m)^{2} - 71 = (3x)^2
$$

Taking $10^m = Y, 3x = X$,

$$
80Y^{2} - X^2 = 71
$$

This is also a Pell equation.

We may solve those Pell equations to find solutions for $n$.

Comment: I like the idea, but I don't see how it solves the problem.  Your Pell equations will have infinitely many solutions $(X, Y)$; how can you tell whether the corresponding values of $Y$ are powers of $10$?

Comment: @RaviFernando, good point. I found this paper which addresses this.

Chakraborty, Kalyan and Luca, Florian. "Perfect powers in solutions to Pell
equations". Revista Colombiana de Matemáticas
Vol 43(2009)1, pp71-86. url (accessed Oct 27, 2022):http://www.scielo.org.co/pdf/rcm/v43n1/v43n1a07.pdf

Comment: This approach is quite clever and with knowledge of elliptic curves can easily be salvaged by taking $n$ modulo 3 instead! That way you have (three) elliptic curves (rather than two Pell equations) and it then has only finitely many points which you can determine explicitly

Answer (score 1):

We do not know of any other solutions and apparently, there are none. However, we can identify aquares in which at least *half* the digits preceding the terminal $1$ are all $8$.

To do this we consider the square roots of $...888881$ in $10$-adics. Since $...888881$ is a $10$-adics square ending with $1$, we can plug in the Maclaurin series

$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac12x-\frac18x^2+\frac3{16}x^3-...$

and it converges to one root which, carried out to six digits, is

$...179641.$

We then generate four six-digit numbers whose squares will end with five $8$'s and then a $1$:

$179641^2=32270888881$

$(500000-179641)^2=320359^2=102629888881$

$(500000+179641)^2=679641^2=461911888881$

$(1000000-179641)^2=820359^2=672988888881$

We see that the smallest square has five out of ten digits preceding the $1$, which is indeed half. With $820359^2$ we get a bonus, as this gives seven out of eleven digits properly equal to $8$.

With any number $n$ of digits taken from the $10$-adic root, the square of the four derived integer roots will have at least $n-1$ $8$'s preceding the final $1$, and the smallest of the four squares will have no more than $2n-1$ total digits (because this root is less than $10^n/4)$. So that square has half the digits preceding the final $1$ equal to $8$, as claimed.

We get a "bonus", like with $820359^2$ above, when the Maclaurin series happens to give a $0,4,5$ or $9$ before the digits we took. Here we took six digits ($...179641$), but a calculation of the Maclaurin series to eight digits would have given $...4\color{blue}{9}176941$. The blue $9$ correlates with an extra eight appearing in $820359^2$. Having a $4$ before that $9$, in the eighth position from the right, turns out to produce a second extra eight giving a total of seven out of eleven digits preceding the final $1$.

Comment: Of the numbers obtained this way, $29641^2 = 878588881$ appears to be the closest to what we want - only two of the digits are wrong!

Comment: Right, although my "bonus" is defined in terms of the contolinuoys stringbif $8$'s. Of course other $8$' may pop up earlier in the square more or less at random, or at the beginning by carefully designing the initial digits of the integer root.